# adding menubar to vertical position of frame using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to add `menubar` to vertical position of frame. i tried this thing already:

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(jMenuBar1, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

but it seems like a temporary solution. I can't edit menus properly 
so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm just a ratchetty old user, but that just sounds like a horrible user experience. May you could use a `JToolBar` which is designed to be layout vertically and horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a vertical menu bar. We need to change the layout manager of the `JMenuBar` component. Try using the below code which creates a vertical menu bar:

```
LayoutManager grid = new GridLayout(0,1);
jMenuBar1.setLayout(grid);
setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
```

this should solve your issue.

Comment: can i limit the with of this grid. currently width occupy full frame width.

Comment: Yes you can limit it by adding your menubar to a new JPanel and adding the newly created panel to your frame as per your requirement. Also @MadProgrammer 's point to use `JToolBar` is also a good solutions as per the user experience.

Comment: actually i need sub menu also so tool bar i think will not full fill my requirement. And thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer if this post helped you. Thanks!